Fetching data from data file using a GraphQL Apollo Server in a NextJS (app route)
I am using Next.js 14 (app route) , React and graphql apollo framework. I have a file with data value in JSON format saved as local file. I want to display the data , using the server api. How do I achieve this?
I have the following Json , that I want to render. Other files have the code that I have setup as base, as first time using all these techs.
   data.json
    {
      "people": [
        { "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe" },
        {  "firstName": "Jane", "lastName": "Smith" },
        {  "firstName": "Alice", "lastName": "Johnson" }
       
      ]
    }

resolver.ts 

    const resolvers = {
        Query: {
          hello: () => 'world',
        },
    
        
      };  
      
      export default resolvers;

    Typedef.ts 
    const typeDefs = gql`
    
     type Query {
        hello: String
      }
    
    `;
    
    export default typeDefs;   

    route.ts
    const graphql = new ApolloServer({
        typeDefs,
        resolvers,
       
      });
    
    
    
      export const config = {
        api: {
          bodyParser: false,
        },
      };
      
    const handler = startServerAndCreateNextHandler(graphql); 
    export async function GET(request: Request) {
          return handler(request);
        }
        
        export async function POST(request: Request) {
          return handler(request); 
        }


         Apollo client 
            export const { getClient } = registerApolloClient(() => {
             return new ApolloClient({
              cache: new InMemoryCache(),
              link: new HttpLink({
              uri: "http://localhost:3000/api/graphql",             
            }),
          });
        });


I tried using registerApolloClient too and it worked for me locally but not on production deploying to Vercel.
I don't know if this is best practice, but I use executeOperation to query my graphql schema without making an http request. The docs only talk about using it for testing purposes.
I use prisma and using React Server Components I can query the database directly using prisma but I was having trouble using the existing graphql schema to utilize the prisma queries I already had set up.
So you can do something like this:
From your route.ts file export the ApolloServer
export const graphql = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
  });

Then in another file you can have a function like this:
export const fetchData = async () => {
    const result = await graphql.executeOperation(
       {
          query:  gql`
                    query GetData {
                      data {
                         id
                         other_property_in_db
                      }
                    }
                   `
        },
        {
           contextValue: yourContextHere
        }
     )
   return result;
  }

You'll have to log result to see what shape the object gets returned in.  You'll get a GraphQLResponse object.  See different section of the docs on executeOperation.  You'll probably have to do something like
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result))

to get something you can pass down to a client component.
Finally you can import and call your function in your page.tsx server component like
const Page = async () => {
   const result = fetchData();

   return <SomeComponent data={result} />
}

I hope this at least points you in the right direction.
